# Github action is not working with external jar files available in java project with ANT build

Tags: java, github, ant, github-actions

I have a java project which is using ANT. I have created github workflow as following:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with ANT
      run: ant -buildfile build_git_workflow.xml test
        
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      if: failure()
      with:
        name: build-reports
        path: build/reports
```

This java project has some libraries (jar files) in a folder (in project/lib directory). When github workflow was executed, these libraries were not considered by compile target of ant.

Ant compile target to add external libraries:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Here is the error from github workflow:

```
[javac] Compiling 548 source files to /home/runner/work/JavaProject/build/classes/enterprise
[javac] error: error reading /home/runner/work/JavaProject/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[javac] error: error reading /home/runner/work/JavaProject/lib/activation-1.1.1-sources.jar; error in opening zip file
```

The same ant target is working fine on local machine as jars are available. On github workflow, external libraries are available, but it is not working. I have tried the similar github workflow with gradle and it works as expected. Any suggestion would be appreciated.